# shrl vs sarl .. x86 Assembly gnu

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu, bit-shift

I'm compiling my code with gcc and looking at the assembly, what is this code exactly doing?

```
shrl $20, %edx
leal (%edx,%eax), %eax
sarl 1, %eax
```

Say that the variable X is at the edx register, and Y is at eax and both are (32-bit int). What is going on here??

I know 'shrl $20, %edx' is shifting %eax right 20 bits, so is same as: eax/(2^20)
and then sarl is the same so 'sarl 1, %eax' = eax/(2^1).
Is that right, and if so what does leal do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that `sarl 1, %eax` is really supposed to be `sarl $1, %eax`, then the whole thing equates to:

```
x = ((unsigned int) x) >> 20;
y = (x + y) >> 1
```

The `leal` instruction means: `eax = eax + edx`.  This [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax) might be useful to you, as well as [this one](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate).